# R regex - How to list every part of a string to what it matched exactly?

Tags: r, string, split

I have a list of strings and a list of regex motifs that I want to match in **R**. If there is a match, I would like to see what each of the characters matched exactly.
e.g. the string `TAPQQATD` and motif `"P.Q.{2}D"` can be matched with str_match but it only produces this as an output:

```
> str_match('TAPQQATD', "P.Q.{2}D")
     [,1]    
[1,] "PQQATD"
```

Now, I know that I can edit each motifs to contain capture groups around each character (like `"(P)(.)(Q)(.{2})(D)"`) , but I would prefer not to, *due to their number*. So can I produce something like this in R (maybe with an other function) BUT with the expression of `"P.Q.{2}D"`?

```
> str_match('TAPQQATD', "(P)(.)(Q)(.{2})(D)")  
     [,1]     [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]  
[1,] "PQQATD" "P"  "Q"  "Q"  "AT" "D"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add the brackets using `gsub`.

```
stringr::str_match('TAPQQATD',
                   gsub("(.\\{\\d+?\\}|.)", "(\\1)", "P.Q.{2}D", perl=TRUE))
#     [,1]     [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,] "PQQATD" "P"  "Q"  "Q"  "AT" "D"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_match_all` from the `stringr` library:

```
x <- "TAPQQATD"
str_match_all(x, "(P)(.)(Q)(.{2})(D)")

[[1]]
     [,1]     [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "PQQATD" "P"  "Q"  "Q"  "AT" "D"
```

Or in base R, `regmatches`:

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("(P)(.)(Q)(.{2})(D)", x))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this also does not work without the capture groups :( I would only like to have the basic regex motif "P.Q.{2}D"

Comment: ...to do what you want in general would require writing a regex parser of some sort.  Out of my pay grade unfortunately.